# ThingsBoard Docker container deploy resulting in `PSQLException`

Tags: postgresql, docker, thingsboard

I want to deploy [ThingsBoard](https://thingsboard.io/) as a Docker container. I use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/thingsboard/tb-postgres) image and I try to overwrite some environment variables to get connection with an external Postgres database.

I simply have a Postgres running on `localhost:5432` with (empty) database `thingsboard`, I create the Docker volumes `mytb-data` and `mytb-logs` and I launch:

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 -p 5683:5683/udp -v mytb-data:/data -v mytb-logs:/var/log/thingsboard -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/thingsboard -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=<MY_PASSWORD_HERE> --name mytb --restart=always thingsboard/tb-postgres
```

The container starts, but the logs report the following error:

```
2020-11-03 07:55:40,480 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: relation "admin_settings" does not exist
  Position: 152
... [OMITTED]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "admin_settings" does not exist
  Position: 152
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
        ... 166 common frames omitted
pg_ctl: could not send stop signal (PID: 9): No such process
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This looks like the database is not prepared. In manual installation you will run the script `/usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh` to do this. I'm not sure if this is done automatigically by the docker scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variables shall be delimited with quotes `'[...]'` in Docker launch command.

This is not necessary in Docker Compose.

For Docker, launch

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 -p 5683:5683/udp --name thingsboard --restart always -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL='<URL>' -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME='<USERNAME>' -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD='<PASSWORD>' thingsboard/tb-postgres
```

Moreover, I was able to solve the issue using the following configuration (Docker Compose, similar for Docker):

```
thingsboard:
container_name: thingsboard
image: thingsboard/tb-postgres
restart: always
environment:
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/thingsboard
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=<USERNAME>
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>
ports:
    - '9090:9090'
    - '1883:1883'
    - '5683:5683/udp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside mytb-data is created the postgres folder call db, or if you have the db postgres folder in another place do the next in that place.
I consider you have DB folder in the ...mytb-data/db you have to do the next:
chown -R postgres mytbpe-data/db

Because the folder db is created with another user and is the user postgres who is going to use that folder, with this most probably you will fix the problem, I had the same problem and with this I fixed it.